# trying to convert array of list to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am trying to convert array key/value pair to an object using map and formEntries function i am getting an error `message:'Object.fromEntries is not a function'` any idea about the fix

main.js

```
  const data = {}
  const channelsMap = new Map(details.channels);
    const channels = Object.fromEntries(channelsMap);
  data = channels;
```

expected output

```
data : {
 channels: {
   "EM": true,
   "SMS": false
}
}
```

data

```
  { details: {
       "channels": [
          {
            "channelType": "EM",
            "isActive": "true"
          },
          {
            "channelType": "SMS",
            "isActive": "false"
          }]
    }
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nodejs server

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` is only supported in node versions 12+

Comment: @mars using 10.16.3

Comment: @evolutionxbox any alternate ?

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over the object.

Comment: There's a polyfill [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-object)

Comment: Use a polyfill? https://vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/objectfromentries/

Comment: @Barmar yes for loop is one approach i was looking for more efficient way to achieve this task

Comment: Perhaps you're JavaScript version isn't supported. It's ES2019.

Comment: What do you think `Object.fromEntries()` does internally? It's basically just a `for` loop that creates an object from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the `details.channels` array into an object where the `channelType` is the key and the `isActive` is the value.

```js
const original = {
  details: {
    channels: [
      { channelType: "EM"  , isActive: true  },
      { channelType: "SMS" , isActive: false },
    ]
  }
};

const transformed = {
  data: {
    channels: original.details.channels
      .reduce((acc, { channelType, isActive }) =>
        ({ ...acc, [channelType]: isActive }), {})
  }
};

console.log(transformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Polywhirl is there typescript way of doing this ? getting this `Binding element 'channelType' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your Node version to something above v12.0.0 should do it. This method isn't included in your current Node version. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Answer (score 0):

first is not allowed to use const when you want to change the value ,
second this is the code to expected output :

```js
let data = {channels:details.channels.map(channel => ({[channel.channelType] : JSON.parse(channel.isActive) }))};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var data={data:{channels: Object.assign(...olddata.details.channels.map(
          obj=> ({[obj.channelType]: JSON.parse(obj.isActive)})))}};
```

data

```
{
    "data": {
        "channels": {
            "EM": true,
            "SMS": false
        }
    }
}
```